# How to assign the output of a function to a variable in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, function

This has been already discussed, but I have a more different problem:
I have a function that needs to be called with `$@` as parameter.

If I put `var=$(function $@)` I just receive errors for every line where the function actions.

Meanwhile I used a workaroud:

1. I called the function first: `function $@`
2. Then I stored into the variable the result from the function: `var=$?`

But this works just if the function return is "succes" or "fail".
Any thoughts?

Code:

```
function()
{
    if [ $1 -gt $x ]
    then
        return 0
    fi

    if [ $1 -eq $x ]
    then
        return 1
    fi

    if [ $1 -lt $x ]
    then
        return 2
    fi
}
```

I want to store in my variable 0 , 1 or 2.
For this:

```
menu ()
{
    if [ $# -gt 5 ] || [ $# -lt 1 ]
    then
        echo "Error! Script is: " $0
        return
    fi

    echo "Insert reference number: "
    read x

    while [ $# -gt 0 ]
    do
        rez=$(function $@)

        if [ $rez -eq 0 ]
        then
            echo "Nr >!" $1
        fi

        if [ $rez -eq 1 ]
        then
            echo "Nr =!" $1
        fi

        if [ $rez -eq 2 ]
        then
            echo "Nr <!" $1
        fi
        shift
    done
}
```

Comment: Please show some actual code and exact (verbatim) output/errors.

Comment: A bush function cannot return anything except success or failure. http://m.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions

Comment: `function` is a bash builtin keyword. I suggest to peplace both "function" by "foobar".

Comment: Yes, sorry. I just replaced my functions name (that was not in English) in a common name, for not creating any confusions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Maybe use `elif`s so that you don't receive multiple values that are returned (also a case statement might be a better solution).
2. `var=$(function $@ >/dev/null 2>&1; echo $?)` should do what you want, I believe?

Comment: My task says so: return 0 for ... 1 for ... and 2 for .... I just need those returns.

What exactly is that code line doing, can u please explain?
It works just as I want, indeed.

Comment: It's executing your function while redirecting both stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`, ensuring there's no output from your function unintentionally stored in the variable. It then echoes the return value, which gets saved in the variable.

Comment: If the functions return somehow an error, will it still be visible if I use /dev/null?

Comment: No; if you want to keep some verbosity (but still only record the return value in the variable), you could use: `var=$(function $@ >&2; echo $?)` instead, which would redirect all output except the return value to stderr.